# limit the number of threads viewed on a page

Tags: php, mysql

In forums, there is an option to choose to display the number of viewable threads on a single page, there is also links to view next pages that contain the same number of thread counts.I would like to learn how that is done in mysql and php.                                                                                            Date and pay me!I WILL DO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
    $max_results=30;
    $current_start = $_REQUEST['step']; // put and get from query string via hidden , or other html field.
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $current_start,$max_results");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            .....
        }
    $current_start+=$max_results;
?>
......
<input type="hidden" name="step" value="<?=$current_start;?>">
......
```